# Icon/Image at start of Div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place an 17x17 px png image at the beginning of a centered div text like that:

```
   [img] text text
text text text text text
text text text text text
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; height: 45px; width: 200px">
        <img src="icon" />
        <div>
            Some longer text.
        </div>
</div>
```

The "difficulty": The text must remain in the div and the div must not contain anything but the text. And the div also must stay a div, or at least must have a height property.

I tried a lot with css but it never works out how I need it. Thanks!

EDIT: The text inside the div is not necessarily long. It can also be just one word.

Comment: where is the problem? what do you aspect?

Comment: Ahhh, homework :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pseudo-element [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/::before) to display your image inside your div:

```css
#myDiv::before {
    content: url('image.png');
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cnx3rtuL/).

Comment: thanks ! problem is the img src in my code is not static but bound with angular (property binding). I dont think you can bind css like that?

Comment: I don't really know how angular work, but if you can generate your css maybe it can be done. Can you use a img tag inside your div, like in your example ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something along these lines:

- A header to have the icon and the title centered
- A section with the rest of the text

And that can easly be done with some lines of flex box. Something along these lines:

```
 <header class="center-text">
  <img src="https://forum.starmen.net/include/images/smilies/cool3.png" /> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, eum, debitis earum dignissimos nobis quos, nulla voluptates temporibus voluptatum ad repellat, nam dicta. Recusandae
  ea quasi eligendi, nulla labore molestias.
</header>
<section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint voluptatem, id fuga adipisci dolor ut deleniti, est provident quis expedita nostrum ipsum sunt maiores obcaecati esse repellat tempore sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint voluptatem, id fuga adipisci dolor ut deleniti, est provident quis expedita nostrum ipsum sunt maiores obcaecati esse repellat tempore sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint
  voluptatem, id fuga adipisci dolor ut deleniti, est provident quis expedita nostrum ipsum sunt maiores obcaecati esse repellat tempore sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint voluptatem, id fuga adipisci dolor
  ut deleniti, est provident quis expedita nostrum ipsum sunt maiores obcaecati esse repellat tempore sed. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis sint voluptatem, id fuga adipisci dolor ut deleniti, est provident quis expedita
  nostrum ipsum sunt maiores obcaecati esse repellat tempore sed.
</section>

<style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.center-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
</style>
```